# Kettle (spoon) - get filename for excel output from field in the excel field in input

Tags: excel, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm trying to process an excel , I need to generate una excel file for each row and as filename I need to use one of the fields in the row.

The excel output hasn't the option "Accept filename from field" and I can't figure out how to achieve it.

thanks

Comment: So all the data of an individual spreadsheet is contained in one row? Are you planning to create spreadsheets with only one row of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the rows into memory and then loop it across the excel file to generate multiple files. You need to break your solution to 2 parts. First of all, read all the rows from Excel Input step into "Copy rows to Result" step as a variable. In the next transformation, use the same variable to use it as a file parameter.

Please check the two links:

- SO Similar Question: [Pentaho : How to split single Excel file to multiple excel sheet output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543009/pentaho-how-to-split-single-excel-file-to-multiple-excel-sheet-output/27303851#27303851)
- Blog : https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the step is mostly made for outputting the rows to a single file, not making a file for each row.

This isn't the most elegant solution but I do think it will work. From your transformation you can call a sub-transformation (Mapping) and send a variable to it containing the filename. The sub-transformation can simply do one thing: write the file, and it should work fine. Make sense?