# Pentaho : Send email based on grouped data

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to create a job in pentaho that can automatically sent an email with excel attachments, but the excel data is depends on the receiver email

1. The source data is from table named 'Report', it has 3 columns :
   `ReportName,PIC,PIC_Email`
2. The query will be : `select * from Report`, but at the end of the process I want that every PIC will get an excel based on their data. So its like PIC 'Tomy' will only get all report name that belongs to him (`select * from report where PIC ='Tomy'`)

is anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the new details you have provided as an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77090304/5040684, your idea is near what you can do, but not completely possible:

- I think the first step (select all the data in table **report**) is not necessary, you have to select the data again for each email, so you don't need all the data first.
- The second step, store a list of values in a variable, is not possible, or you haven't expressed the idea in "correct Pentaho" way. A variable stores a single value, not a list, so if you want to store all the values in it (I don't think is necessary, more on that later) you would need to create a single text value with all the mails to store in the variable, and then to extract each mail from the variable. What you need in the second step is pass in a loop each mail to the variable. You have to do this in a job, a transformation in Pentaho doesn't allow to change the value of a variable/parameter when running, you set the value or have a unique value for each execution of the transformation.

So how could you do this? Various ways, something similar to your idea would be this job:

[image: Job example]

After taking the screenshot, I think the second transformation (**Read Report for each email**) needs to be a job, because you can't generate an excel with multiple rows and send only a job in one transformation, you need to separate it in two transformations, but the configuration for a job instead of a transformation is similar, so I'm not creating a new screenshot.

So, the first transformation to read the emails would be like this:
[image: Select emails transformation]

You use the **Copy rows to result** step to pass the emails to job executing the transformation. So the list of emails are passed to the **Read Report for each email** job (remember, in my screenshot I've use a transformation but it needs to be a job to send only one email):
[image]

So in the job properties you define the parameter you are going to pass in the parent job. You'll use that parameter in the send mail step of the job.

Now, in the transformation **Select Report for email**, you again define the same parameter name as in the job executing the transformation, and use the parameter in the select, and probably in the excel name you generate:
[image: Select Report for email transformation]

Comment: I would recommend using Metadata Injection step instead of "copy rows to result" as a best practise, wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pretty standard actions

You create a list of users (id, name, salutation, email-adres, etc). via f.e. table input, text input, datagrid. Then you send them 1 by 1 into a transformation and include the data as parameters. In the transformation you run a query to receive data from database based on the userid, and then you run the resulting rows to an excel file which you save, and include in the mail. The mail you send to receiver based on parameters set before. So the mail step will only send one mail per run, but the whole transformation will be repeated for each user in the initial set.

Not sure where your difficulty is here, and which part to elaborate. If needed, comment and i will try to do so.

Comment: For a more detailed comparable answer, i would point you to the answer of Ana, below here. She describes it pretty well

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic in my mind, is it posible to do this in pentaho ?

1. Input data (select * from report)
2. store the list of email in variable (select distinct email from report)
3. execute the query (select * from report where email = ${email})
4. sent mail
5. loop the step 3 and 4 by the data in ${email}

Comment: You have given more details to your question as an answer, this is not correct as of StackOverflow guidelines, the correct procedure in this case, as this doesn't modify your original question, would be editing your original question, marking clearly what and when (as you already have answers) you have modified the original, and maybe add comments to answers you have received to give notice that the original question has more details. In other cases when you are adding a new step to your original question, opening a new one about the new step is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of steps provided by PDI to deal with such situations.

1. **Using "Copy rows to Result" approach**

This is a standard solution that uses looping across a transformation based on a parameter/variable. In PDI it can be achieved by the use of "Copy rows to result" which will use internal pentaho memory to store the PIC / Emails. Please [read this blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/) to understand the use of "Copy Rows to Result".

- Similar, [Pentaho : How to split single Excel file to multiple excel sheet output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543009/pentaho-how-to-split-single-excel-file-to-multiple-excel-sheet-output/27303851#27303851) was also asked in SO. Will help you for reference.
- A sample code using copy rows is available on [github](https://github.com/rishuatgithub/Pentaho/tree/master/stackoverflow-pentaho-samples/MultipleExcelSheet) for reference.

2. **Metadata Injection Step**

This is a cleaner approach in my opinion. In PDI, you can create a transformation to use as a template for your repetitive tasks. This transformation is known as the template transformation. The template transformation is a child transformation that is reused by the ETL Metadata Injection step with the metadata created from various input sources.

More on ["Metadata Injection Step"](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.4/Products/ETL_metadata_injection) in the PDI wiki.